# How to achieve Arial Narrow in bold face

Tags: fonts, luatex, fontspec

I am not quite understanding why I am not able to achieve bold face Arial Narrow font with the following mwe.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}

% N.B. typeset with lualatex.exe

% uncomment this section and observe result
%\usepackage{fontspec}
%\setsansfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Arial Narrow}
%\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault}
% uncomment this section and observe result

\titleformat*{\section}{\normalsize\bfseries}

\begin{document}
\section{A \emph{bold} section heading}
\titleformat*{\section}{\normalsize}
\section{A not so \emph{bold} heading}
\section{Just an ordinary heading}
\end{document}
```

Perhaps the font variants don't exist on my system or period?

Comment: Which operating system and which TeX distribution do you employ?

Comment: @andselisk, thanks for the interest.  You're link appears to me to have all of the headings formatted similarly.  Can you see Arial Narrow + boldface?

Comment: @JohnChris Sorry, I should've read more carefully. No, there is no boldface for me either:(

Comment: On a MacOS/MacTeX system, your code works just fine, i.e., there are the ordinary and bold weights, and there are the upright and slanted (not true italic) font shapes.

Comment: W7, MikTeX 2.9.6630 64-bit

Comment: You need to check if Arial Narrow is installed on your system.

Comment: @Mico, thanks.  I seem to recall installing it... not recalling off the top of my head where I would have put it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have the same issue despite the fact Arial Narrow is installed properly. Declaring shapes explicitly helps to overcome the problem (for the record, I'm using Windows 10 with standard fonts set and up-to-date TeXLive 2018):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}

% N.B. typeset with lualatex.exe

% uncomment this section and observe result
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setsansfont[
        Ligatures=TeX,
        BoldFont={Arial Narrow Bold},
        ItalicFont={Arial Narrow Italic},
        BoldItalicFont={Arial Narrow Bold Italic}
    ]{Arial Narrow}
\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault}
% uncomment this section and observe result

\titleformat*{\section}{\normalsize\bfseries}

\begin{document}

\section{A \emph{bold} section heading}
\titleformat*{\section}{\normalsize}
\section{A not so \emph{bold} heading}
\section{Just an ordinary heading}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

As it's been pointed out in the comments, Arial font family is proprietary and may or may not be installed on the system. As a failsafe option I'd recommend to use [Liberation Sans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liberation_fonts) fonts, which are

> free metric-compatible substitute for the Arial, Arial Narrow, Times New Roman and Courier New fonts.

<sup><sup>Source: [Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/fonts)</sup></sup>

Switching to `Liberation Sans Narrow` works without shapes declaration:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}

% N.B. typeset with lualatex.exe

% uncomment this section and observe result
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setsansfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Liberation Sans Narrow}
\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault}
% uncomment this section and observe result

\titleformat*{\section}{\normalsize\bfseries}

\begin{document}

\section{A \emph{bold} section heading}
\titleformat*{\section}{\normalsize}
\section{A not so \emph{bold} heading}
\section{Just an ordinary heading}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This woks on my W7, MikTeX 2.9.6... system.  Thanks.

Comment: You may want to add a note that whilst it worked on your win 10 it probably wont work for most users since win 10 does not include Arial Narrow (it was often included for win 7 with pre-installed MS trials see https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/typography/font-list/arial-narrow) Its possible some win 10 users downloaded and installed alternatives such as the mac compatible ones here https://github.com/potyt/fonts/tree/master/macfonts/Arial%20Narrow I just tested on 10 and with these installed and MiKTeX task font maps updated it removes the MiKTeX error of **"ArialNarrow"** [sic] font not found

Comment: @KJO Even though I remember having it around for the past decade virtually on every PC I used (most likely from the MS Office installations), I admit that it's a proprietary font and may not be available. For those unfortunate users there is a substitution font, *Liberation Sans Narrow*.